# Logstash error when using if statement in pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, logstash, elk

I am trying to determine if a field exists in a log file and if so, use the value of that field as part of the index name. If the field does not exist, use a different index name.

```
  beats {
    port => 5000
  }
}
filter {
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://elasticserver.io:9243"]
    user => "user"
    password => "pass"
    retry_on_conflict => "2"
    if [index_append] {
      index = "%{[@metadata][beat]}%{index_append}"
    }
    else {
      index = "%{[@metadata][beat]}"
    }
    "action" => "create"
  }
}
```

If I remove the if statements in the output section and just either one of the index options (index = "%{[@metadata][beat]}%{index_append}", or index = "%{[@metadata][beat]}") the pipeline loads fine, but doesn't account for when the field 'index_append' exists or not.

I have tried many combinations, but the logstash logs seem to indicate some sort of syntax issue.

```
[2021-06-09T17:17:38,658][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:"LogstashPipeline", :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"=>\" at line 14, column 8 (byte 259) after output {\n  elasticsearch {\n    hosts => [\"https://elasticserver.io:9243\"]\n    user => \"user\"\n    password => \"pass\"\n    retry_on_conflict => \"2\"\n    if ", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:184:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:69:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/reload.rb:53:in `execute'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:389:in `block in converge_state'"]}
```

I tried moving the if statements to the filter section, but receive the same error in logstash logs. I have used similar if statements in other pipelines and have not had these types of issues. I copied the code to VS Code and verified that there were no extra spaces or characters. I'm at a loss.

This pipeline is running on Logstash 7.10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the conditional to the filter section. Use a field under [@metadata] to store the index name. By default [@metadata] does not get written by the output so it is useful for storing temporary variables.

```
if [index_append] {
  mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][index]" => "%{[@metadata][beat]}%{index_append}" } }
} else {
  mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][index]" => "%{[@metadata][beat]}" } }
}
```

Then reference it in the output using

```
index => "%{[@metadata][index]}"
```

Comment: That worked. However, I had to change the else section a bit.

Comment: Sorry about that, I did a copy and paste of the if section and did not edit the else. Fixed now.